# I want to make a list of this condition using a SparseArray

Tags: list-manipulation

```
TH = 70;
S = 100;

p[i_, j_] :=  p[i, j] /; j == 0 && i == S
p[i_, j_] :=  p[i, j] /; j == 0 && TH < i && i < S       
p[i_, j_] :=  p[i, j] /; j == 0 && i == TH
p[i_, j_] :=  p[i, j] /; j == S - i && S - TH <= i && i < S
p[i_, j_] :=  p[i, j] /; j == TH - i && 0 < i && i < TH
p[i_, j_] :=  p[i, j] /; j == TH && i == 0
p[i_, j_] :=  p[i, j] /; j == TH && 0 < i && i < S - TH
p[i_, j_] :=  p[i, j] /;  0 < j && j < TH && (TH - j) < i && i < (S - j) 
p[i_, j_] := 0
k = SparseArray[Function[{i, j}, p[i, j]], {S, TH}] // Flatten
m = DeleteCases[k, 0];
o = Total[m];
```

As a premise, $ S $ is greater than $ TH $.I want to make a list of this condition using a `SparseArray`. I want to set the elements outside the condition to 0. However, I am in trouble because I can not output well. Please tell me what's different! Thank you.

Comment: You have given the conditions for nonzero elements, but not the values. What values do you want to set these elements to? For example in the first line, when $j=0$ and $i=S$, what shall be the value of the element $p[S,0]$?

Comment: In that case, it becomes p [100, 0]. @Roman

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
ClearAll[condition]
condition[S_, TH_][i_, j_] :=  p[i, j] Boole @ Or[j == 0 && i == S,
   j == 0 && TH < i && i < S,
   j == 0 && i == TH,
   j == S - i && S - TH <= i && i < S,
   j == TH - i && 0 < i && i < TH,
   j == TH && i == 0,
   j == TH && 0 < i && i < S - TH,
   0 < j && j < TH && (TH - j) < i && i < (S - j)];


S = 10; TH = 7;
sa = SparseArray[{i_, j_} :> condition[S, TH][i - 1, j - 1], {S, TH}];
MatrixForm[sa]
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{ccccccc}
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & p(1,6) \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & p(2,5) & p(2,6) \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & p(3,4) & p(3,5) & p(3,6) \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & p(4,3) & p(4,4) & p(4,5) & p(4,6) \\
>  0 & 0 & p(5,2) & p(5,3) & p(5,4) & p(5,5) & 0 \\
>  0 & p(6,1) & p(6,2) & p(6,3) & p(6,4) & 0 & 0 \\
>  p(7,0) & p(7,1) & p(7,2) & p(7,3) & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  p(8,0) & p(8,1) & p(8,2) & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  p(9,0) & p(9,1) & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

```
Total[sa, 2]
```

> p[1, 6] + p[2, 5] + p[2, 6] + p[3, 4] + p[3, 5] + p[3, 6] + p[4, 3] + 
>    p[4, 4] + p[4, 5] + p[4, 6] + p[5, 2] + p[5, 3] + p[5, 4] + p[5, 5] +
>     p[6, 1] + p[6, 2] + p[6, 3] + p[6, 4] + p[7, 0] + p[7, 1] + 
>    p[7, 2] + p[7, 3] + p[8, 0] + p[8, 1] + p[8, 2] + p[9, 0] + p[9, 1]

Comment: You forgot some matrix elements somehow, the middle anti-diagonal is supposed to be filled.

Comment: @Roman, thank you;  i must have missed one of the conditions. I will check.

Comment: There's actually only one condition; all others are redundant. See my post.

Comment: @Roman, i had the `S` and `TH` switched. Fixed now.

Comment: Thank you for your advice

Comment: @Kenta, my pleasure. Thank you for the accept.

Answer (score 3):

You have two symbols `p` that need to be disentangled. Let's call one `P` instead:

```
TH = 70;
S = 100;

P[i_, j_] := p[i, j] /; j == 0 && i == S
P[i_, j_] := p[i, j] /; j == 0 && TH < i && i < S
P[i_, j_] := p[i, j] /; j == 0 && i == TH
P[i_, j_] := p[i, j] /; j == S - i && S - TH <= i && i < S
P[i_, j_] := p[i, j] /; j == TH - i && 0 < i && i < TH
P[i_, j_] := p[i, j] /; j == TH && i == 0
P[i_, j_] := p[i, j] /; j == TH && 0 < i && i < S - TH
P[i_, j_] := p[i, j] /; 0 < j && j < TH && (TH - j) < i && i < (S - j)
P[i_, j_] := 0

k = SparseArray[Table[P[i, j], {i, 0, S}, {j, 0, TH}]] // Flatten
```

Alternatively, remembering that `SparseArray` indexes the elements starting from 1, not from 0, you can construct `k` directly without first making a large array and then pruning the zeros:

```
k = SparseArray[{i_, j_} /; TH <= (i-1) + (j-1) <= S -> p[i-1, j-1], {S+1, TH+1}] // Flatten;
```

(all your conditions can be simplified into a single condition)

Answer (score 3):

It might be of interest for you to learn about `Band`. Often it is worthwhile to figure out the pattern of a sparse matrix for small sizes and to hardcode the sparsity pattern for large `SparseArray`s with, e.g. `Band`:

```
TH = 700;
S = 1000;

diag = Thread[p[1, Range[0, TH, 1]]];
A = SparseArray[
     Join[
      {
       {S + 1, 1} -> p[S, 0],
       {TH + 1, 1} -> p[TH, 0],
       {1, TH + 1} -> p[0, TH]
       },
      Table[
       Band[{-i, 1}, Automatic, {-1, 1}] -> diag, {i, 1, S - TH + 1}]
      ],
     {S + 1, TH + 1}
     ]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 0.314529

My experiments indicate that the resulting matrix coincides with Roman's, while the matrix is build by an order of magnitude faster this way.

Notice that the three-argument-version of `Band` actually allows to specify _anti_diagonals. Moreover, `SparseArray` works by *last in--last out*; this is why I specify the irregular rules for the first and last columns *before* the regular `Band`s.

Comment: See my comment on @kglr's post about the antidiagonal filling.

Comment: Isn't there a crafty way of producing a broad band? `Band` has a lot of options I'm not familiar with. Including anti-diagonal bands, no need for `Reverse`.

Comment: @Roman Hmmm. I figured out how to create antidiagonals directly. And the documentation also explains how to place block matrices along a band. But all broad bands in the docs are created by assigning each band invidually... Maybe there is some undocument way of doing so. I don't know.

Comment: This, perhaps, speeds the creation of such banded matrices? :o :D you rock for expanding on your methodology, also!