# I want to make an expression list of this condition using SparseArray

Tags: list-manipulation

```
S = 10;
TH = 7;
μe = 60;
μg = 30;
λe = 30;

condition[S_, TH_][i_, j_] := sosa[i, j] Boole@Or[
  μe*p[i, j] == λe*p[i - 1, j] /; j == 0 && i == S (*No1*)
  (λe + μe)*p[i, j] == μe*p[i + 1, j] + μg*p[i, j + 1] + λe*p[i - 1, j] /; j == 0 && TH < i && i < S(*No2*)
  (λe + μe)*p[i, j] == μe*p[i + 1, j] + μg*p[i, j + 1] /;j == 0 && i == TH(*No3*)
  (μe + μg)*p[i, j] == λe*p[i - 1, j] /;j == S - i && S - TH <= i && i < S(*No4*)
  (λe + μe)*p[i, j] == μe*p[i + 1, j - 1] + μe*p[i + 1, j] + μg*p[i, j + 1] /; j == TH - i && 0 < i && i < TH(*No5*)
  λe*p[i, j] == μe*p[i + 1, j - 1] + μe*p[i + 1, j] /; j == TH && i == 0(*No6*)
  (λe + μe + μg)*p[i, j] == μe*p[i + 1, j] + λe*p[i - 1, j] /; j == TH && 0 < i && i < S - TH(*No7*)
  (λe + μe + μg)*p[i, j] == μe*p[i + 1, j] + λe*p[i - 1, j] + μg*p[i, j + 1] /; 0 < j && j < TH && (TH - j) < i && i < (S - j)(*No8*)];

sosalist = SparseArray[{i_, j_} :> condition[S, TH][i - 1, j - 1], {S + 1,TH + 1}]
```

As a premise, `S` is greater than `TH`. I want to make an expression list of this condition using `SparseArray`. I want to set the element outside the condition to 0, but I am troubled because I can not output well. Please tell me what's different! Thank you very much.

Comment: Could you please provide the definition of the functions sosa[] and p[] such that we can try to run your code. It would also help if you removed all but one or two of the conditions, such that we have a minimum example to work with rather than the full code...

Comment: What is the difference to [this post of yours](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/198553)?

Comment: @Henrik Schumacher  It's a little different.I want to create an expression specified in the corresponding element of p.